# What is the maximum recommended expiry for an OAuth2 refresh token?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am trying to work out if there is a maximum recommended expiry for a refresh token in the OAuth2 standard. Ideally, I would like to find concrete recommendations that take into account the nature of the secure interaction or any associated risks (eg personal data).

Background- The OAuth2 standard provides a mechanism for obtaining new access tokens using a refresh token. Access tokens are expected to have a 'short' expiry and refresh tokens a 'long' expiry.

There are many examples online that talk about access and refresh token expiry durations for different applications ([example](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/oauth/refresh-token)), but none of these come with particularly strong rationale or a clear justification for a particular length.

This is for a healthcare application where data security is critical. We would like to use a long refresh token length (90 days) but I haven't been able to find guidance to help me understand the risks of using such a duration.

I'm working from: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Answer (score 2):

The question that comes to mind is why 90 days if the data sensitivity is critical? A session time such as 30 minutes seems like a better option. Is this related to poor login usability where users forget passwords? If so, OAuth can help. Some notes of mine here may help a little .. https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/

Comment: Thanks - I will read the guidelines. Yes indeed the issue is related to login usability and also the potential for the patient to go offline for a long period (eg on holiday). The specific application context is for a clinical trial, where it is very important to avoid introducing any hurdles to the patient using the application. It is possible that patients would drop off the trial if we force them to login again; we are also restricted in terms of the authentication experience due to the clinical trial setting - we cannot hold any personally identifiable information such as email address.

Comment: Depends also on the type of OAuth client - if it is a web UI then 90 day security is difficult to secure - for desktop and mobile apps you can use secure os storage and 90 days is easier to justify